# Solving a function using periods of time.

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I'm just working on some summer problems so that I can be more prepared when I go into my class in the fall. I found a website full of problems of the content we will be learning but it doesn't have the answers. I need a little guidance on how to do this problem.
Here is the problem:

Jose takes medication. After $t$ minutes, the concentration of medication left in his bloodstream is given by $A(t) = 10(0.5) ^{0.014t}$ , where $A$ is in milligrams per litre.

a. Write down $A(0)$
Would this = $0$ because nothing has happened yet?

b. Find the concentration of medication left in his bloodstream after $50$ minutes.
Do I plug $50$ in for $t$?

c. At 13:00, when there is no medication in Jose’s bloodstream, he takes his first dose of medication. He can take his medication again when the concentration of medication reaches $0.395$ milligrams per litre. What time will Jose be able to take his medication again?
Do I plug in $0.395$ for $A$ and then solve for $t$?

Comment: a) To get $A(0)$ put $t=0$ in $A(t) = 10(0.5) ^{0.014t}.$ b) You're right. c) You're right. You need to solve $A(t) = 10(0.5) ^{0.014t}=0,395.$ And, of course, add the minutes to 13:00.

Comment: $A(0)$ is immediately _after_ Jose took the medication, so there is certainly more than $0$ medication in his bloodstream. Things don't always start from zero.

Comment: @mfl To solve for c, could I change it to 0.014t=log5(0.395) by using the changing formula between exponents and logarithms and solve from there?

Comment: Note that $10(0.5)^0.014t=0,395\implies (0.5)^0.014t=0,0395$ (The 10 on the RHS divides the LHS). Now, taking logarithms, you have $0,014t\log 5=\log 0,0395.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On point a, to explain a little, since it seems to be causing you some confusion.

The question is vague about the way Jose "takes" his medication – was it injected, or did he swallow it?

If it was injected, which is easier to consider for this question, you will get a curve like the [following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharmacokinetics#/media/File:Iv_time_conc_curve.svg).

That is, a rapid increase in blood concentration, to a **maximum amount**, followed by an exponential *decline*.

What is equal to 0 in part a, is the **time** in minutes, and obviously not the concentration, which is it at its **maximum amount** at 0 minutes. It is all “downhill” after that, so to speak.

The way I look at these sort of exponential decay rates is as follows:

> CurrentConcentration = **InitialAmount** × *RateOfChangePerUnitTime* ×
>   **AmountOfTimeUnits**

Which for you, converts to:

> A(t) = **10** × *(0.5)<sup>0.014</sup>* × <sup>**t**</sup>

Since t = 0, this then resolves to:

> A(t) = 10 × (0.5)<sup>0</sup>

And I interpret (0.5)<sup>0</sup> to physically mean “the decay rate has not been applied”, i.e. the drug concentration has *not begun to decay*, according to its *RateOfChangePerUnitTime*.

All of which means that:

> A(0) = 10

which I presume to be in units of concentration (mg/mL etc.)

The pharmacokinetics are different, and more confusing for these calculations, if he swallowed it – the curve looks like [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=1366&bih=635&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=34RrW47MIorGgAawgpmoDw&q=pharmacokinetics%20oral%20dose&oq=pharmacokinetics%20oral%20dose&gs_l=img.3...332537.332932.0.333117.4.4.0.0.0.0.88.333.4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0....0.-aTmqhUBeYA#imgrc=oBMnkPzDxeq_qM:).

Answer (score 0):

1. calculate $A(0)$ means put $t=0$ in the given eqn
2. calculate $A(50)$ means put $t=50$ in the given eqn
3. plug $0.395$ in place of $A(t)$ and calculate $t$ and add the time $t$ to $13:00$ to get the required time

$$0.395=10(0.5)^{0.014t}$$
now we can write it as $$0.395/10=(0.5)^{0.014t}$$
now I am taking the log of both side
 $$log(0.0395)=log{(0.5^{0.014t})}$$
 $$log(0.0395)=0.014t*log{(0.5)}$$
 $$\frac{log(0.0395)}{log(0.5)}=0.014t$$
 $$\frac{-1.4034029}{-0.301029996}=0.014t$$
$$4.66200352=0.014t$$
$$\frac{4.66200352}{0.014}=t$$

which gives t=333.0002526 minutes

thus total $\frac{333}{60}$ hours which is 5 hours 33 minutes thus new time is 18:33

Comment: For c, I got 13:41. Does this seem correct?

Comment: How did you get *t*? I changed it into a logarithm. 0.014t=log5(0.395) and solved from there.

Comment: I haven’t learned any of this before, it’ll be new content I learn this year in school. So it’s very confusing for me, I apologize. I might wait until we get to this unit to understand. I just don’t know how you get to solving it, or why. I changed it into a logarithm because I felt that made sense based on how the equation was already set up. I don’t know what ln means. Thank you so much for your help for the first parts though , I got those!

Comment: ln is same as log  ln is called natural with the base e where e is Euler constant but the log is generally written with base 10

Comment: have you seen the updated solution do you have anything to ask??